# Cannot Understand the TOP command output on Hadoop Datanode

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, metrics

Hi I just installed Cloudera Manager on my cluster, 1 namenode and 4 datanodes, each data nodes has 64 GB RAM, 24 cores Xeon CPU, 16 1T disks SAS..etc.

I installed brand new Redhat Linux and upgraded to 6.5, each disk has been logically set up as RAID0 since there is no JBOD option available on the array controller.

I am running a hive query and here is the top command on the data node. I am so confused and wondering if some experienced hadoop admin could help me understand if my cluster is working fine.

1. Why there is only 1 task running out of 897 while the other 896 sleeping? There are 2271 mappers for that hive query and it is only 80% on the mapper side.
2. The load average is 8.66, I read from [here](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2009/07/31/understanding-load-averages) that if you computer is working hard, the load average should be around the number of cores. Is my datanode working hard enought?
3. List item 69/70 memory has been "used", seems like the active yarn process is fairly low memory cost, how could those 64GB memory be so easily used up?

Here is the `top` output:

```
top - 22:50:24 up 1 day,  8:24,  3 users,  load average: 8.66, 8.50, 7.95

Tasks: 897 total,   1 running, 896 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 32.3%us,  5.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 62.3%id,  0.2%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  70096068k total, 69286800k used,   809268k free,   222268k buffers
Swap:  4194296k total,        0k used,  4194296k free, 61468376k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                   
  439 yarn      20   0 1417m 591m  19m S 193.9  0.9   1:06.12 java                                                                                                                      
  561 yarn      20   0 1401m 581m  19m S 193.2  0.8   0:19.75 java                                                                                                                      
  721 yarn      20   0 1415m 561m  19m S 172.0  0.8   0:08.54 java                                                                                                                      
  611 yarn      20   0 1415m 574m  19m S 127.0  0.8   0:16.87 java                                                                                                                      
  354 yarn      20   0 1428m 595m  19m S 121.4  0.9   0:35.96 java                                                                                                                      
27418 yarn      20   0 1513m 483m  18m S 13.6  0.7  18:26.14 java                                                                                                                       
16895 hdfs      20   0 1438m 410m  18m S  9.6  0.6 103:23.70 java                                                                                                                       
 3726 hdfs      20   0  860m 249m  21m S  1.7  0.4   2:12.28 java
```

I am fairly new at system admin and any metric tool or common sense will be much appreciated! Thanks!